Use qprompt on Raspberry Pi 5
I am trying to run the application qprompt on a Raspberry Pi 5 with 8GB RAM.
To do that I followed the instructions from the Cannonical Snapcraft installation instructions. Installation works find, but starting the application runs into errors:
myuser@mysystem:~ $ qprompt 
/snap/qprompt/6/snap/command-chain/desktop-launch: line 633: /snap/qprompt/6/usr/bin/qprompt: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error
/snap/qprompt/6/snap/command-chain/desktop-launch: line 633: /snap/qprompt/6/usr/bin/qprompt: Success

The system I have installed is the most recent Raspberry Pi OS 64-Bit which is based on Debian 12 Bookworm. What must be done to run the application qprompt? Could there be a missing library that needs to be installed?
